# How to show custom field and parent post id in wordpress attachment page (image.php)

Tags: custom-field

I'm trying to use code to show custom field outside the loop in
wordpress attachment page (image.php) it's returns nothing.

this is the code i'm used to show the custom field:

```
<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'my-custom-field', true);
?>
```

and i'm trying to show parent post id in attachment page too
with `get_the_id` and use this code

```
<?php global $wp_query;
$this_page_id = $wp_query->post_parent;
$post_id = get_the_id($post->ID);
echo $post_id ;?>
```

but the code above just shown the attachment ID
not the parent post ID.
anyone can help, please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have `$post` object on `image.php`. Don't complicate and use following:

```
<?php
echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my-custom-field', true);
echo $post->post_parent;
```

Comment: work well like i wanted, thnks Max